# Using flatbuffers struct as a key

Tags: flatbuffers

I am considering using flatbuffers' serialized `struct` as a key in a key-value store. Here is an example of the `struct`s that I want to use as a key in rocksdb.

```cpp
struct Foo {
  foo_id: int64;
  foo_type: int32;
}
```

I read the documentation and figured that the layout of a `struct` is deterministic. Does that mean it is suitable to be used as a key? If yes, how do I serialize a `struct` and deserialize it back. It seems like `Table` has API for serialization/deserialization but `struct` does not (?).

I tried *serializing* `struct` doing it as follows:

```cpp
constexpr int key_size = sizeof(Foo);
using FooKey = std::array<char, key_size>;

FooKey get_foo_key(const Foo& foo_object) {
  FooKey key;
  std::memcpy(&key, &foo_object, key_size);
  return key;
}

const Foo* get_foo(const FooKey& key) {
  return reinterpret_cast<const Foo*>(&key);
}
```

I did some sanity checks and the above seems to work in my Ubuntu 18 docker image and is blazing fast. So my questions are as follows:

1. Is this a safe thing to do on a machine if it passes FLATBUFFERS_LITTLEENDIAN and uint8/char equivalence checks? Or are there any other checks needed?
2. Are there any other caveats that I should be aware of when doing it as demonstrated above?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to go via `std::array`, the `Foo` struct is already a block of memory that is safe to copy or cast as you wish. It needs no serialization functions.

Like you said, that memory contains little endian data, so FLATBUFFERS_LITTLEENDIAN must pass. Actually even on a big endian machine you may *copy* these structures all you want, as long as you use the accessors to read the fields (which do a byteswap on access on big endian). The only thing that won't work on big endian is casting the struct to, say, an `int64_t *` to read the first field without using the accessor methods.

The other caveat to certain casting operations is strict aliasing, if you have that turned on certain casts may be undefined behavior.

Also note that in this example `Foo` will be 16 bytes in size on all platforms, because of alignment.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. Can you also comment on whether it is safe to use the above struct as a key. That is, a given struct object will have exactly one serialized representation and vice versa. I think it is so. But hearing that from a flatbuffers contributor would give me more confidence. :)

Comment: Yes, it should be safe to use as key, as the binary representation should always be the same. There's even explicit padding in the struct with `0`s to ensure that.